# Parse a string that contains delimiter

Tags: java, string, algorithm, parsing

So, I am trying to write a function and parse a string and put them into a hash and the user can choose which separator/delimiter they use.

Exmaple:
Parse(input,separator)

It is easy to parse a string if sub string does not contains separator,
For example:
ABC.ASD.ASD.D.WE.R.Q.VF.G.R.T.QWE.E.ERRR

Parse by(".") is easy, but what if the sub string contains the delimiter.
For example:
Math131.Math141.Math151.Math.161,
in the second case, how would you define the rules/parse functions?

Thanks
Sen

Comment: This is exactly why programming languages require escapes before delimiter characters that should not be interpreted as delimiters. E.g. in java "\"". The backslash prevents the following quote from being interpreted as a delimiter.  So this is the string consisting of one double quote. Consider requiring the input to your function to use the same approach: Math\.161 Another convention (originally from BASIC, I think), is for any double occurrence of a delimiter to be interpreted as a single character (not a delimiter). So the input in your problem case would be Math..161

Comment: There are escape for the backslash if it is the delimiter that user wants, but the user can input any delimiter and any input...

Answer (score 4):

I see three possible approaches:

1. You can prevent this situation from arising to begin with by ensuring that you have good (well-specified) input data.
2. You can use traditional programming methodologies, where you start by formalizing your requirements and figuring out your precise intended behavior, then you implement that.

   - In the case of `Math131.Math141.Math151.Math.161`, the rule might be "a list element consists of one or more letters, optionally followed by `.`, followed by one or more digits"; then you can split using the regex `\.(?!\d)` (a `.` that's not followed by a digit).
3. You can use machine learning approaches, where you obtain huge numbers of examples of correctly-split strings, and use those examples to train a neural network to split strings as desired. Note that this will not have a 100% success rate.

#1 is probably the best approach if you can manage it, but I see that you're still in college, so #2 and #3 might be good learning experiences.

Comment: Personally I prefer the #1 as I thought it about myself. But ya, this is for work, and the customers are weird and wanted this way.....Because the program supports 20+ languages and i think some of them are bit weird, but thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If the type of input is well-defined, you could construct a regular expression to parse your input string. Expanding on the example you've specified, you could do something like (and I apologize if "." is not a wildcard in Java):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Math\.+\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Notably, the above does not care what the delimiter is per-se. You just define what a valid token would look like as a regular expression. That way you can account for possible deviations from the norm. It then loops through all of the matches and prints them. Of course you could have it do whatever you like with the matches instead.

Comment: I think you meant `"Math\.?\d+"`. The period is not required, and there can be at most one of them.

Comment: It is good if the input is well define. But the input could be anything that the user types in, and the delimiter is provided by the user as well, and he provided me cases where the inputs contains the delimiter...